# How to AutoLogin in multiple clients if logged in one client in Cognito?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, amplifyjs

My use case is where i have one cognito user pool and various client apps inside it. If i login in one of the application - i need to autoLogin in another application.

Things i tried

- tried setting cookie Path to .domain so in another domain i can read those cookies (successful)
- Reading that accessToken and getting user attributes (Successful)
- Trying to get session object using amplify or cognito-identity-js. The idea is to authenticate via attributes decoded from JWT (Does not work, tried configuring Amplify multiple times, reading session or passing custom storage class. This code is written in getServerSideProps)

Any pointers/Alternatives in that directions ?

P.S - i would like to avoid AWS Lamda with custom triggers.

Thanks & Regards,

Comment: I don't think you can do it without custom challenges. Any standard authentication requires password and since your  second app does not have it the only option is a custom challenge that you could use to authenticate based on the id token from the first app.

Comment: @AleksanderWons yes based on accesstoken - i want to autologin and yes i managed to do with customchallenge/lambda hooks.

Comment: Then your problem is solved, right?

Comment: @AleksanderWons Can you all elaborate on what steps you took to achieve the same experience?

Comment: Hi please revert @AleksanderWons and the question creator as well